# Providing a temporary monitor to a server in an inconvenient location

Tags: video, remote-access

I have a small server that's tucked away under a cabinet.  Normally it just does its thing, no problems, all via network.  In the rare event that I need to check a boot error, etc, I have to pull it out, set up K/V/M, fix the problem, etc.  The K/M part is easy enough with a single USB dongle.  The video, though, is more challenging.  So, I'll describe my ideal solution, and perhaps someone can tell me how close that is to actually existing.

What I would like is some sort of VGA-connected dongle that can receive and transmit the VGA signal to a virtual monitor on my tablet, perhaps over Bluetooth.  So, I would plug in the dongle, it would convert the VGA signal to BT, and my tablet would pick it up and display it on the tablet, perhaps looking much the same as a remote desktop connection (except it's black and white boot screens, not a pretty GUI).

I don't mind a similar option that goes over the network to a PC, or whatever.  It would be convenient to stand right there and work on it, but it's not that much walking.  This isn't a big house.  Also, when I call it a server, I should say it's not really server hardware, so no IPMI options or anything like that.
Finally, the tags I've selected for this are pretty general.  I'd appreciate suggestions on more applicable ones.  Thank you.

Comment: What about just running a long VGA extension cable from the port on the back up to the bench?

Comment: I've considered that, and may do it.  It's doable, but not ideal.  The problem is that the cable would have to go through a couple of doorways and around some corners.  Not a big deal, just annoying to set up.  But that may be what I end up doing.

Comment: You can get RF 'video senders' but my experience of this is hit and miss.

Comment: What brand and model? Maybe it has an iLO to connect remotely.

Comment: I wish... Unfortunately, it's basically an old PC with some extra storage and Linux.  So, more a server by role than by hardware.